# regexp: get percentage number out of text and text itself

Tags: javascript, regex

Example strings with desired results:

a) `"some āē text 12%"`

I need to get "some āē text" and "12%" as seperate items.

b) `"12% some text"`

I need to get "some text" and "12%" as seperate items.

Moreover, I always should be able to identify, where percentage number is in match. So, it is better if in result matches percentage number (12%) would always be second.

**Assumptions:** percerntage number can be at the beginning or at the end of text only. Thus there are no percentage numbers somewhere between words. Also there is only one percentage number within text.

I am not a friend of Regexp yet, but I have tried. 
So far I can write regexp to match if there is text with percentage. But I cannots write regexp that seperated this number from another text.

```
        // text with special characters and percentage
        const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\u017F\s%]+$/gi // I need english + other letters, but not special symbols or brackets
        var matches = str.match(regex);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
let [, textBefore, number, textAfter] = yourString.match(/^(.*?)(\d+%)(.*)$/)
```

There are two assumptions here:

- you can use modern JavaScript (`let`, [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment))
- there's a match

If those aren't verified, you could also write

```
var match = yourString.match(/^(.*?)(\d+%)(.*)$/);
if (match) {
    var textBefore = match[1];
    var number = match[2];
    var textAfter = match[3];
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this syntax. It is somehow new to me.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes. Although it's probably more useful *not* to capture the % char

Comment: @renathy if you want to see the regex explanation you can use this for that: https://regex101.com/r/F2syjU/1/ (see right panel)

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to underts. Btw, I have to match also my special symbols as I showed in description. I can fix it bymyself, but please add it also in the answer, so that it is precise :)

Comment: @renathy I'm sorry but I don't understand this part of the requirement. You mean you additionally want to check there's no "special symbols" in the texts before and after ?

Comment: I meant not special symbols, but special letters from some other languages. Look at my first example, I have special letters. ā and ē. I managed to regexp them like this: [a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\u017F].

Comment: You mean you want something like `(/^([a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\u017F]*?)(\d+%)([a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\u017F]*)$/)` ?

Comment: Probably, yes. Just instead of English chars, I want to include other language chars.

Comment: I need these letters to spport. [a-zāēūīšģķļņž]

Answer (score 0):

[This following regex](https://regex101.com/r/fRNODG/3) produces 2 groups (not necessarily in this order):

- A substring of different characters (can also be special symbols)
- A number with percentage sign

The only assumption here is that these two parts have a space between them.

```
^(\d+%) (.*)|(.*?) (\d+%)$
```